# How to add rasters to a mosaic from a feature class with raster attribute fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I want to create a mosaic from rasters stored as raster attribute fields inside a feature class.

When I run Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset I get the following error:

`2015-02-07T18:59:39.439: Error: 8004203f: Could not open source as a raster dataset. [c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\bin\<msg>1;2015-02-07T18:59:39.449: Error: 80040213: Failed to open raster dataset`

Does anybody know why I get this error and how to avoid it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Table raster type, you can add the following to your mosaic dataset:

- Raster catalog
- Mosaic dataset
- Table with paths
- .dbf file (for example, from a footprint shapefile)

So what you are doing is not supported!
I couldn't find a way with arcpy to export raster field to a file system (e.g. png) raster. In arcgis documentation it is stated that with da.SearchCursor you cannot access data in raster field [URL](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000)

If writing code in ArcObject is an option for you, you can do it with this code:

```
public static String getFotovalue(IRow pRow,String nombreCampo){   String result = "";   try   {
    String tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
    tempPath = tempPath.Remove(tempPath.Length - 1);
    IWorkspaceFactory pWSF = new RasterWorkspaceFactory();
    IRasterWorkspace pRasWS = null;

    pRasWS = (IRasterWorkspace)pWSF.OpenFromFile(tempPath, 0);

    IRasterValue pRV = (IRasterValue)pRow.get_Value(findField(pRow, nombreCampo));
    IRasterDataset pRDS = pRV.RasterDataset;
    if (pRDS.CanCopy())
    {
      ISaveAs psa = (ISaveAs)pRDS;
      IRasterDataset pOutRDS = (IRasterDataset)psa.SaveAs("copyname.jpg", (IWorkspace)pRasWS, "JPG");

      result = pOutRDS.CompleteName;
    }                                  }   catch   {   }   return result; }
```

If you can't write code, then you should export each raster one by one (no automation)

Comment: Hi Farid, thanks for your answer. Yes I had a feeling it might not be possible to create a mosaic based on fc raster attributes. But I found an Australian ESRI website where they show how to export raster in attribute fields. Which is strange since the documentation as you mentioned states it is not possible using arcpy.da.SearchCursor. I post the code in a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Since it might not be possible to directly create a mosaic based on raster attribute fields I will use Farids approach with exporting the rasters to individual files.

This  [website](https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/how-to-export-your-raster-datasets-referenced-in-a-raster-attribute-field-file-geodatabase-using-python/) shows how it is done using arcpy. I changed the code a little to this

```
import arcpy
fc = r"C:\temp\data.gdb\bornholm"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("raster", "Name")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        filename = "{0}.tif".format(row[1])
        arcpy.AddMessage( filename)
        try:
            row[0].save("c:/temp/"+filename)
        except:
            arcpy.AddWarning("Error exporting raster")
```

Comment: Did you test this code to see whether it works?

Comment: Yes, it does work